# Updating Views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, view

I am creating a view to show the user his/her data, but I also want the user to be able to make changes in some of the fields in those views. Are the changes made in a view reflected in the base table as well?

Also, would I be able to update a view that is made up of more than one base table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As documented under [Updatable and Insertable Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/view-updatability.html):

> Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such as [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html), [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html), or [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) to update the contents of the underlying table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable. To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the following:
>
> - Aggregate functions ([`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min), [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max), [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count), and so forth)
> - `DISTINCT`
> - `GROUP BY`
> - `HAVING`
> - [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) or [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html)
> - Subquery in the select list
> - Certain joins (see additional join discussion later in this section)
> - Nonupdatable view in the `FROM` clause
> - A subquery in the `WHERE` clause that refers to a table in the `FROM` clause
> - Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying table to update)
> - Uses `ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE` (use of a temporary table always makes a view nonupdatable)
> - Multiple references to any column of a base table.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable, assuming that it can be processed with the `MERGE` algorithm. For this to work, the view must use an inner join (not an outer join or a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html)). Also, only a single table in the view definition can be updated, so the `SET` clause must name only columns from one of the tables in the view. Views that use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) are not permitted even though they might be theoretically updatable, because the implementation uses temporary tables to process them.

Comment: I checked the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS table and my view is updatable. But when i try to update it from a non admin user ID i get the error "Error Code 1142: UPDATE command denied for user 'abc' for table 'view' ". Although i have explicitly granted update privilege on the particular view. Any idea why would i be getting this error?

Comment: @mishra I'm guessing, but perhaps the user also needs permissions to modify the base tables from which the view is generated. You may not want to do this.