# Can`t create an updatable view in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I try this:

```
CREATE VIEW ALL_urls AS 

SELECT * FROM TABLE1_urls 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE2_urls
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE3_urls
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TABLE4_urls
```

But when i search in "information_schema" i get this:

```
IS_UPDATABLE
NO
```

Any idea how make it "updatable"?

Comment: Check the following SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793722/updating-views-in-mysql

Comment: there's no way to make it updatable, with a JOIN for example? im not a mysql expert.

Comment: With a UNION, in your case.

Comment: Why not store all the urls in one table to begin with ?!?!?!

Comment: @Devart i cant use UNION or UNION ALL that said the link posted above, and i cant store all urls in one single table.

Comment: @Strawberry i cant, cuz they are urls from diff sources.

Comment: I think you're stuck then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such
>   as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying
>   table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one
>   relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the
>   underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a
>   view Non-Updatable.

To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the following:

- Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
- DISTINCT GROUP BY HAVING UNION or UNION ALL Subquery in the select
- list Certain joins
- Nonupdatable view in the FROM clause
- A subquery in the WHERE
- clause that refers to a table in the FROM clause
- Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying table to update)
- Uses ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE (use of a temporary table always makes a view non-updatable) 
  -Multiple references to any column of a base table.

It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable,

> Assuming that it can be processed with the MERGE algorithm. For this
>   to work, the view must use an inner join (not an outer join or a
>   UNION). Also, only a single table in the view definition can be
>   updated, so the SET clause must name only columns from one of the
>   tables in the view. Views that use UNION ALL are not permitted even
>   though they might be theoretically updatable, because the
>   implementation uses temporary tables to process them.