# Trying to remove Duplicates from Table, But getting 1288 MYSQL error, the target table Delete is not updatable

Tags: mysql, sql

The query is working fine without delete statement,
but do not know why it is throwing error when I am trying to remove Duplicates from tables
newemployees.

```
With newemployees as
(select empid, empname, salary,
 row_number() over (partition by empid order by empid) as ROWNUMBER from employees) 
 delete from newemployees where ROWNUMBER !=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot update/delete/insert from/to a "table" created with WITH. IT does not exist in the dbms. It is similar to trying to update a view. There are very strong rules on when (if possible) a view can be updated. See this answer:

[Updating Views in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793722/updating-views-in-mysql)

Comment: Actually I saw i below links, dont know how they say it shud work.

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/

http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-query-to-delete-duplicate-rows#:~:text=SQL%20query%20to%20delete%20duplicate%20rows%201%20Method,a%20row%20unique%20identifier%20%28auto%20incremental%20ascending%20order%29

Comment: It is DBMS dependent. It might be possible to be done in sqlserver (the article you are citing).